# pass same switches, parameters to install multiple MSI files -- after parsing directory for all *.MSI pattern matches

Tags: batch-file, wildcard, windows-installer

*(Sorry for not wording this more concisely -- I'm not sure how to summarize it.)*

I have a large directory of source files -- all MSI's.
Rather than scripting a separate commandline for each and every file, I would prefer to:

1. call ALL of them using *.msi pattern match (or similar).... and have each of them run with "/passive /norestart".
2. (optional) also include the "/liew" parameter, and substitute 
   "[the first part of the filename].log"

I already tried:

```
FORFILES /P 3DxSoftware64\. /M *.msi /S /C "msiexec @path /passive /norestart"
```

... but it fails; it just launches the dialog options for "MSIEXEC /?"; doesn't actually call the file @path itself.
However, if I remove the whole "/C '...'" string,  then it *does* echo the filenames (with full paths) correctly.

I've tried various ways of piping the results, e.g.

```
/C echo @path | msiexec
```

but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?
My source, which led me to this point:
- http://www.ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

Thanks for any assistance!!
-- Joseph

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you missed this part of the Options Dialog:

```
…
Install Options
    </package | /i> <Product.msi>
        Installs or configures a product
…
```

This means you are invoking the installation packs incorrectly. Instead of

```
msiexec @path …
```

it should be either

```
msiexec /package @path …
```

or

```
msiexec /i @path …
```